# Auto Complete coming up with strange suggestions

Tags: auto-correct

The auto complete on my LGL41C android is coming up with strange suggestions, this started in the last couple of weeks.

Type "Wash" and the number one suggestion was 'Washingtonu' the phone has a languge setting of English (Settings > Language & Inputs > Language)

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard also has a language setting, that can be different from the phone.

Go to (Settings > Language & imputs > Language > LG Keyboard > Input Language and type)  Select your preferred language (English) and keyboard type (QWERTY)

Comment: I searched google and andriod.se without finding this suggestion, stumbled across solution (after way to long).  I believe random butt dialing my have changed the default setting to Bahasa (top of the list)